# Python SMTP with text body and file attachment

Tags: python, smtp

I am trying to open a text file and mail that in the body in plain text, I also need to attach several other log files to the e-mail.

```
import smtplib
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText 
from email.MIMEMessage import MIMEMessage

recipient = 'people@people.com'

def mail (recipient, ):

        fp = open('data.txt', 'r')
        msg = MIMEText(fp.read())
        fp.close()
        me = "jeff@noname.com"
        msg['Subject'] =  "Test Results" 
        msg['From'] = me
        msg['To'] = recipient
        s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
        s.sendmail(me, recipient.split(), msg.as_string())
        s.quit()

mail (recipient, )
```

This currently will open the data.txt file and put all  of the contents into the e-mail body.  This is working how I want to, and I need to keep this.  But I also want to add 4-6 attachments to the e-mail and keep the body.  Anyone have any tips to help with this?

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you-

```
import smtplib
import os
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEBase import MIMEBase
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
from email.Utils import COMMASPACE, formatdate
from email import Encoders

def send_mail(send_from, send_to, subject, text, files=[], server="localhost"):
    assert type(send_to)==list
    assert type(files)==list

    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = send_from
    msg['To'] = COMMASPACE.join(send_to)
    msg['Date'] = formatdate(localtime=True)
    msg['Subject'] = subject

    fp = open('data.txt', 'r')
    msg.attach(MIMEText(fp.read()))
    fp.close()

    for f in files:
        part = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
        part.set_payload(open(f, "rb").read())
        Encoders.encode_base64(part)
        part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="%s"' % os.path.basename(f))
        msg.attach(part)

    smtp = smtplib.SMTP(server)
    smtp.sendmail(send_from, send_to, msg.as_string())
    smtp.close()

send_mail() # don't forget to provide the required parameters here before executing the code
```

Comment: Not working for me, But Im not exactly sure where I have to fill in parameters

Comment: @Aladine you have to fill the parameters inside the `send_mail()` function call. Also, as **localhost** is set as the server in this code, you can't send any mails without a local email server running on your machine. I hope you know that. By the way, you can use **gmail's smtp server**, they work great but will require some modifications to the above code.